# Profinet Communication with Python

Tags: python, ethernet, raw-ethernet

I am trying to write python code for Profinet communication (send - receive data) but I don't have much information. I'm looking for something to guide me. Where should I start? What should I look for ? Please help me thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://github.com/devkid/profinet

Comment: @kutschkem I tried but doesnt work that codes.